# Why won't summarize_if work with bind_rows in this example?

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, bind, summarize

I am trying to use `bind_rows` and `summarize_if` to add a total bottom row in a sample data set.  There are different postings that are related to this type of question, but not exactly my issue.  Additionally, some posted questions have so much other code and data that I wind up spending more time trying to figure out the code and example instead of how the answer applies more generally.

With that in mind, I have a simple sample data set.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

sample_pivot_data <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
                                "C", "C", "C"), Season = c("Winter", "Summer", "Winter", "Fall", 
                                                           "Spring", "Winter", "Fall", "Spring", "Winter", "Summer", "Summer"
                                ), Expense = c("Insurance", "Rent", "Utilities", "Misc", "Insurance", 
                                               "Rent", "Utilities", "Insurance", "Rent", "Utilities", "Misc"
                                ), Fixed_Variable = c("Fixed", "Fixed", "Variable", "Variable", 
                                                      "Fixed", "Fixed", "Variable", "Variable", "Fixed", "Variable", 
                                                      "Variable"), Amount = c(300, 200, 400, 300, 800, 400, 200, 300, 
                                                                              450, 230, 120)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"))


# A look at the data:

    > sample_pivot_data
# A tibble: 11 x 5
   Group Season Expense   Fixed_Variable Amount
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
 1 A     Winter Insurance Fixed             300
 2 B     Summer Rent      Fixed             200
 3 A     Winter Utilities Variable          400
 4 A     Fall   Misc      Variable          300
 5 A     Spring Insurance Fixed             800
 6 B     Winter Rent      Fixed             400
 7 B     Fall   Utilities Variable          200
 8 B     Spring Insurance Variable          300
 9 C     Winter Rent      Fixed             450
10 C     Summer Utilities Variable          230
11 C     Summer Misc      Variable          120
```

I found a similar problem which was addressed in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946873/how-do-i-add-a-row-to-a-data-frame-with-totals) which gave me this solution which works:

```
# This works, no syntax issues

my_pivot <- sample_pivot_data %>%
  group_by(Group, Fixed_Variable) %>%
  summarize(category_total = sum(Amount)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Fixed_Variable, values_from = category_total) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(GrandTotal = rowSums(.[-1])) %>%
  bind_rows(summarize_all(.,                                                                 
                          funs(if (is.numeric(.))
                            sum(.)
                            else
                              "Grand_Total"))
            ) %>%
  print()


    # A tibble: 4 x 4
  Group      Fixed Variable GrandTotal
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A           1100      700       1800
2 B            600      500       1100
3 C            450      350        800
4 Grand_Total 2150     1550       3700
```

When I tried to do the same thing, but use summarize_if with the below code, I get an error:
**Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function"**  I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489511/r-error-in-usemethodtbl-vars) as a possible solution to the error, but I didn't follow how this applied in this case.

```
# This does not work

my_pivot2 <- sample_pivot_data %>%
  group_by(Group, Fixed_Variable) %>%
  summarize(category_total = sum(Amount)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Fixed_Variable, values_from = category_total) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(GrandTotal = rowSums(.[-1])) %>%
  bind_rows(summarize_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  print()
```

If someone could explain why the above doesn't work I would appreciate it.  On a related note, I also tried `bind_rows(summarize_all(., list(~if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Grand_Total" )))` which worked but RStudio kept giving me an indication that parenthesis were unmatched...perhaps a different question, but I figured I would mention rather than posting an entirely separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `.` in `summarize_if()`. This works fine:

```
my_pivot2 <- sample_pivot_data %>%
  group_by(Group, Fixed_Variable) %>%
  summarize(category_total = sum(Amount)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Fixed_Variable, values_from = category_total) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(GrandTotal = rowSums(.[-1])) %>%
  bind_rows(summarize_if(., is.numeric, sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  print()
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Group Fixed Variable GrandTotal
  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A      1100      700       1800
2 B       600      500       1100
3 C       450      350        800
4 NA     2150     1550       3700
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think I needed the dot there, as in this starwars example:  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html